# Using pointers for a "like" relationship in parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm am fairly new to ios programming and to parse, so if i am not explaining something clearly ill be more than happy to try my best to expand on this.

In parse i have three tables `User` `Activity` and `post` the code i have now works well for a "following" relationship but does not for a  "like" relationship, i want to take the object id from the `Post` table and the object id of the user that is liking the post from the `User` table, and insert them in to the `Activity` Table. Any help will be appreciated, Thank you in advanced.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
if (indexPath.section == self.objects.count && self.paginationEnabled) {
    [self loadNextPage];
    }
}

 - (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
 [query includeKey:@"User"];
 query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
 [query whereKey:@"filter" hasPrefix:@"90"];
 [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];


    return query;

}




 - (void)likeButton:(LikeButton *)button didTapWithSectionIndex:(NSInteger)index {
PFObject *post = [self.objects objectAtIndex:index];
[post fetchIfNeeded];
PFUser *user = post[@"User"];

if (!button.selected) {
    [self likePost:user];
}
else {
    [self unlikePost:user];
}
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}





 - (void)likePost:(PFUser *)user {
if (![user.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
    [self.likeArray addObject:user.objectId];
    PFObject *likeActivity = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Activity"];
    likeActivity[@"fromUser"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    likeActivity[@"toPost"] = user;
    likeActivity[@"type"] = @"Like";
    [likeActivity saveEventually];
   }
}
- (void)unlikePost:(PFUser *)user {
[self.likeArray removeObject:user.objectId];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[query whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query whereKey:@"toPost" equalTo:user];
[query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"like"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *likeActivities, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *likeActivity in likeActivities) {
            [likeActivity deleteEventually];
        }
    }

    }];
}
```

Comment: Parse have a video tutorial for the very thing you are trying to do

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/one-to-many-relationships

Comment: so in my `- (void)likeButton:(LikeButton *)button didTapWithSectionIndex:(NSInteger)index` method i would declare two  pfobjects?

Comment: Yes you would indeed

Comment: im having trouble understanding how exactly to do it, could you give me an example please?

Comment: I'm not at my desk at the moment.  If you haven't sorted it by tomorrow I'll post an example

Comment: Thank you so much ill, let you know tomorrow if i have figured it out or not.

Comment: i tried everything i could think of yesterday, could you post an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first off I would mention that you should be very careful with case-sensitivity. String matches in Parse are case-sensitive so if you create it with `type:@"Like"` and then try to find it with `whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"like"` you won't get a match!

Now, as for your code, you want to link the current user to the selected post right?

If so here's a sample of what you should do instead:

```
- (void)likeButton:(LikeButton *)button didTapWithSectionIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    PFObject *post = [self.objects objectAtIndex:index];

    if (!button.selected) {
        [self likePost:post];
    }
    else {
        [self unlikePost:post];
    }

- (void)likePost:(PFObject *)post {
    [self.likeArray addObject:user.objectId];
    PFObject *likeActivity = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Activity"];
    likeActivity[@"fromUser"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    likeActivity[@"toPost"] = post;
    likeActivity[@"type"] = @"like";
    [likeActivity saveEventually];
}
```

Looks like your code was copy-pasted from your "follow" logic but not updated to reflect the fact that you're now doing a "like", so I've fixed that for you. You'll need to make similar changes to your `unlikePost:` method too.